# Facebook like plugin multiple thumbnail

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, plugins

I am having trouble with the Facebook like plugin, i am trying to use multiple thumbnails.

Site address http://www.colourmyiphone.co.uk?

How i have set up my site:

The page titled Store, pulls all the products out from the product table. Each product will have a link to the item page. This works by the link passing on a "type" (the item id) to the item page. From there the item page will know which information to pull from the item table.

I have added the Facebook Like plugin on the item page.

The plugin works fine, what i can not get to work is the thumbnails. I want the thumbnail to be a image of the item the user has liked. What is happening now is that a few items thumbnails are showing the image, my logo or nothing.

```
function display_front_images(){


$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['type']);

$itemfront = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM item WHERE id = \"$id\" and view = 'front' ") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($itemfront))
{
$image = $row['image'];
$name = $row['name'];
$colour = $row['colour'];
$id = $row['id'];

echo "<div class=\"product_holder_front\">

      <img class=\"product_front\" src=$image>

        <div class=\"front_text_title\">

        <span class=\"$colour\">$name </span> </br></br>

          <div class=\"front_text\">What do you get? </br>
          &#8226;  New Coloured Front Panel</br>
          &#8226;  New LCD Screen</br>
          &#8226;  New Digitiser</br>
          &#8226;  New Earpiece Dust Cover</br>
          &#8226;  New Home Button</br>

          <div class=\"fb-like\" data-href=\"http://www.colourmyiphone.co.uk/display_item.php?type=$id\" data-layout=\"standard\" data-action=\"like\" data-show-faces=\"true\" data-share=\"true\"></div>


          </div>

        </div>

      </div>";

 }
}
```

any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.colourmyiphone.co.uk%2Fdisplay_item.php%3Ftype%3D1 to debug how Facebook see your page. Set an og:image to the thumbnail you want for that link

Comment: @WiKid i have been using the Facebook debugger, but what it tells me and what my site does are two different things. Are you able to set multiple og:image tags?